# Smallest voltage a peak circuit can detect

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, circuit-design

I have been looking up peak detector circuit in different sources but I could not find nowhere mentioning the smallest voltage a peak circuit can detect and what factors determine that value. In my application, I have to deal with signals in few millivolts or even down to hundreds microvolts The theory of operation is well explained in every source I found but when dive into the details, it seems to me every factor matters in optimizing a peak circuit such as op amps GBW, diode voltage drop, diode leakage current, type of diodes etc. I would appreciate if anyone could give me a more analytical details in how we design the peak detector

I have copied the peak detector picture taken from : https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltc6244-high-speed-peak-detector.html for reference

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Do you have access to negative voltage for your opamps?

Comment: This can be wrapped up more effectively if you use a simulator and play around with the circuit. Sims are free these days so there’s no excuse not to use one and get virtual experience.

Comment: Key issues in low intensity signal design with OP AMPs  are surely the input offset voltage of the OP AMPs and the common mode rejection ratio CMRR. By working with these two parameter on your circuit I bet you'll be able to find a lower limit  to the voltage of the signal you can detect.